# No sound after Flash GIF is exported

Tags: gif, adobe-flash

I successfully created an animated e-card in Flash cs6 with sound.  Sound and video work great when I test it in the program.  But after I export it as an animated GIF, only the video animation appears, but no sound.  I need the sound to appear in the GIF because I'm using it to email to clients in the body of the email.

Any help would be appreciated.
Rochelle

Answer (score 5):

The GIF format does not, and never has, supported audio. GIF is purely an **image** format.

Comment: OK, so the only way to get audio to export is to save it as an .mov file?  If that's the case, is there a way to insert that file into the body of an email without attaching it, so that all the recipient has to do is click on the email and the video shows right there?

Comment: It is customarily bad form to include any video or audio in an email.  This is why you've *never* gotten an email of that nature. If you *really* want to do this, you need to host the video file on a server somewhere, then link to the video in the email. Most email clients will not support inline video. It is going to *require* a click by the user to load a web link with the video. What you are trying to do is really never done.

Comment: Yes, please do not stick a video file in an email, please.